# Is it possible to forward host USB devices to EDK2's NT32 emulation platform?

Tags: usb, driver, bootloader, uefi

I'm a bit new in UEFI driver development.

I have an UEFI application-bootloader that checks all USB tokens that are currently present in system. It works ok on hardware and Vmware VM, but I would like to test in NT32 emulator from EDK2 to be able to use source-level debugging.

Vmware has required feature for forwarding any removable device from host to VM. I try to do the same for NT32.

Have anyone worked on this issue before? Is it possible to forward USB token? Or maybe this token can be emulated somehow?

Continuous searching haven't gave me much information.
I suspect that it can be done with some tricky settings in package file Nt32Pkg/Nt32Pkg.dsc.

Possibly `gEfiNt32PkgTokenSpaceGuid.PcdWinNtPhysicalDisk` or `gEfiNt32PkgTokenSpaceGuid.PcdWinNtVirtualDisk` parameters can be useful, but I'm not sure.

Thanks everyone in advance for your efforts.